# React Optimisation Using Lazy Evaluation

Tags: function, reactjs, optimization, lazy-evaluation, react-dom

I am brainstorming how I would optimise my React application using lazy functions. Apologies for the lots of text. My thinking has been:

- React has its diff algorithm which computes whether a component & its children have changed since the last update. This involves computing through the component logic, getting the end result & then comparing it against a snapshot of previous computation. NOTE: As React does such a good job, nowadays, its the React's diff algo which can be the most time consuming & that is what I am trying to optimise using lazy functions below.
- My lazy evaluation functions would store the computed value in the first computation session. In the following computation session, if computation of my code is not needed, it will return the stored component state.

Here is where I am confused:

I was under the impression that I can 'somehow' stop React from running its diff algorithm when I know that there is no need for recomputation of the component & its children, i.e. the lazy evaluation returns its stored state rather than recompute & that will allow me to somehow stop React from running its diff algo on this component.

However, I am confused if that is how it is suppose to be. And if it is, how would I go about doing it.

Comment: I think, you should read about shouldComponentUpdate and PureComponent, that is what you want. Writing your own funcion for that is not so good

Comment: @SlawaEremkin good point & thanks for that, yes, mayhaps thats the only place from where to instruct React. Just to clarify, lazy evaluation sits at the state level, kind of like redux, so it certainly has its place in this equation.

Comment: if you need to save computed data, so you should use reselect in mapStateToProps

Comment: I am making use of selectors in redux. however, I have diverted quite a bit from normal React apps, e.g in my app, I have bypassed React's event handler & gone for the dom ones which help me do debounce & throttling. Also, I have my own custom event delegation system on top of that, which helps me immensely with optimising my app further, however, negative includes, my main component is BIG & needs to intelligently pass props to the children (this is where lazy evaluation comes in). Apologies, if the above doesnt make much sense, its terribly short summary.